# match multiple lines from a cisco network config

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to match expression_A AND expression_B from this cisco config using python re module.

**my logic:**

`expression_A = "permit tcp 96.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq www"`

`expression_B = "permit tcp 98.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq telnet"`

if match expression_A AND expression_B then print something.

**config file:**

```
interface Serial1/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
access-list 101 permit tcp 96.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq www
access-list 101 permit tcp 98.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq telnet
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login local
 transport input all
-----------
```

Comment: Since you are searching literal strings, you don't need to use regex at all.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really need a regex, as the `in` operator is enough: `in` checks if one string contains another. When we use `in` in combination with `and`, we can use this code to check if your config string contains both expressions:

```
config = "..." # The contents of your config file
expression_A = "permit tcp 96.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq www"
expression_B = "permit tcp 98.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any eq telnet"

if expression_A in config and expression_B in config:
    print("Match")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Casimir mentioned in a comment you do not need to use RE here.

```
with open('config.txt', 'r') as config_file:
    config = config_file.read()
if expression_A in config and expression_B in config:
    print("something")
```

Answer (score 0):

While regular expressions aren't necessary to match a constant string, as others have noted, you *can* achieve "**does the string match *this* AND *that***" logic by using regex lookaheads, in the form: `(?=.*this)(?=.*that)`, so:

```
(?=.*permit tcp 96\.0\.0\.0 0\.255\.255\.255 any eq www)(?=.*permit tcp 98\.0\.0\.0 0\.255\.255\.255 any eq telnet) //singleline
```

will match only if BOTH strings are present (order would not matter).

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJ5cO9/4)